# nHibernate strategies in a web farm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, nhibernate, caching, web-farm

Our current project at work is a new MVC web site that will use a WCF service primarily to access a 3rd party billing system via a web service as well as a small SQL database for user personalization.  The WCF service uses nHibernate for the SQL database.

We'd like to implement some sort of web farm for load balancing as well as failover and maintenance.  I'm trying to decide the best way to handle nHibernate's caching and database concurrency if there are multiple WCF services running.

Some scenarios I've been thinking about...

1)  Multiple IIS servers, one WCF server.  With this setup, the WCF server would be a single point of failure, but there would be no issues with nHibernate caching or database concurrency.

2)  Multiple IIS servers, each with it's own WCF service.  This removes a single point of failure, but now nHibernate on one machine would not know about database changes done by another machine.

Some solutions to number 2 would be to use an IStatelessSession so we're not doing any caching and nHibernate is always fetching directly from the database.  This might be the most feasible as our personalization database has very few objects in it.  I'm also considering a 2nd-level cache such as memcached or Velocity, but it may be overkill for this system.

I'm putting this out there to see if anyone has experience doing this sort of architecture and to get some ideas for a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: "but I implemented a second-level query cache with nHibernate and it's working great." Can I ask which 2nd level cache implementation you went for and why?

Comment: Memcahced http://memcached.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am i missing something here, i don't see a problem with nhibernate on the webservers.
application cache would not be a problem as each nhibernate box would keep it's own cache which would be populate from the datastore. look at creating a table that can be monitored for reasons to do a cache refresh. we used to do this using using CacheDependency class in .net 2.0 that would detect changes to a column and then remove the relevant item from the cache. so if a user inserts a new product, the cache would be dropped and the next call to get the products would load the cache again. it's old but check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163955.aspx#S2 for the concept. cheers

Comment: Your answer prompted me to do a lot more R&D into first and second level query caching in nHibernate, testing with multiple WCF services, running SQL Profiler and memcached in verbose console mode.  This helped me to better understand what nHibernate is doing under the covers with caching as well as a flaw with my session management in my WCF code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not doing caching until not doing caching becomes a problem.  Your DB will do its own caching to save you searching for the same data repeatedly, so the only thing you have to worry about is data across the wire.  Judging by your description, you're not going to have a problem there.  If you ever get to a stage where you do, use a distributed cache - allowing your servers to cache separately will cause you bouncing data problems on refresh.

Comment: That's definitely a good point.  With the small amount of data we're dealing with, caching probably isn't needed, but I implemented a second-level query cache with nHibernate and it's working great.